# ERROR: The config profile (PhoenixMVP) could not be found while deploying through Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

`rm -rf ~/forcetest_deploy
mkdir ~/forcetest_deploy && cp -r ./. ~/forcetest_deploy && rm -rf ~/forcetest_deploy/.ebextensions/https-redirect-python.config
cd ~/forcetest_deploy/. && rm -rf .elasticbeanstalk
cd ~/forcetest_deploy/. && eb init MyApp --profile PhoenixMVP --region='ap-south-1' && eb deploy && eb open
ERROR: The config profile (PhoenixMVP) could not be found
WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
ERROR: This directory has not been set up with the EB CLI
You must first run "eb init".
WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
ERROR: This directory has not been set up with the EB CLI
You must first run "eb init".
cd ~ && rm -rf ~/forcetest_deploy
echo 'Test deployment successfull'
Test deployment successfull
Finished: SUCCESS`

I am getting the above error while I was trying to deploy my application through Jenkins tool running on my laptop. All the other commands are working. 
I am using Jenkins pipeline, where i have written the deployment script.

PhoenixMVP is present in .aws folder and i am able to deploy without Jenkins.

Anything wrong here? How to setup AWS secret keys in Jenkins?

Comment: are you using this : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-16-04